# How to use query-replace on filesets in emacs

Tags: emacs

[Emacs documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Filesets.html#Filesets) states that you can use query-replace on filesets to perform find/replace on multiple files.

> This lets you perform certain operations, such as visiting,
>   query-replace, and shell commands on all the files at once.

I've opened my particular fileset (i.e. via fileset-open) and attempted query/replace using both:

```
M-%
```

and

```
M-x query-replace
```

but can't get it to work on anything but the file (buffer) I'm currently in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run a command on all the files in a fileset, you have to use the `filesets-run-cmd` function and the command should be one of the commands that are specified in the `filesets-commands` variable. Specifically, in your case, you are supposed to run <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>`filesets-run-cmd`</kbd><kbd>Query Replace</kbd>.

> **`(filesets-run-cmd &optional CMD-NAME FILESET MODE)`**
>
> Run CMD-NAME (see `filesets-commands') on FILESET.

> **`filesets-commands`**
>
> Commands to run on filesets. An association list of names, functions, and an argument list (or a function that returns one) to be run on a filesets' files.